# install minikube in windows failed

Tags: minikube

I am sitting behind firewall, so that I installed vpn. The proxy is 127.0.0.1, port is 1080. I am using win10, disabled Hyper-V since using Oracle virtual box.

I follow the [link](https://medium.com/@maumribeiro/running-your-own-docker-images-in-minikube-for-windows-ea7383d931f6) to install minikube in windows. The below screens is the interaction between my command and response. 
/1/ step 1

```
PS C:\temp> minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.9.4 cluster...
Starting VM...
Downloading Minikube ISO
 142.22 MB / 142.22 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Downloading localkube binary
 163.02 MB / 163.02 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s
 0 B / 65 B [----------------------------------------------------------]   0.00%
 65 B / 65 B [======================================================] 100.00% 0sSetting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Starting cluster components...
Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.
Loading cached images from config file.
```

Step 1 seems ok. Then step 2:

```
PS C:\temp> minikube docker-env
$Env:DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = "1"
$Env:DOCKER_HOST = "tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
$Env:DOCKER_CERT_PATH = "C:\Users\Administrator\.minikube\certs"
$Env:DOCKER_API_VERSION = "1.23"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# & minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression
```

Step 2 seems ok also. Then I step 3:

```
PS C:\temp> minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression
```

Step 3 looks ok. Then I try step 4:

```
PS C:\temp> docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

Step 4, here, I have some doubts, why I do not have same images as the author.
The author images is put below:

[images get by instruction link's author](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ueH0.png)

Well, I continue with following step 5:

```
PS C:\GoWorkspace\src\hello> docker build -t dummy:v0 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/2 : FROM golang:onbuild
onbuild: Pulling from library/golang
ad74af05f5a2: Pull complete
2b032b8bbe8b: Pull complete
a9a5b35f6ead: Pull complete
25d9840c55bc: Pull complete
d792ec7d64a3: Pull complete
be556a93c22e: Pull complete
3a5fce283a1e: Pull complete
0621865a0c2e: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:c0ec19d49014d604e4f62266afd490016b11ceec103f0b7ef44875801ef93f36
Status: Downloaded newer image for golang:onbuild
# Executing 3 build triggers...
Step 1/1 : COPY . /go/src/app
Step 1/1 : RUN go-wrapper download
 ---> Running in e808b8afc9fa
+ exec go get -v -d
github.com/gorilla/mux (download)
Step 1/1 : RUN go-wrapper install
 ---> Running in 3afb95a832a9
+ exec go install -v
github.com/gorilla/mux
app
 ---> 3bd1e6e9ee1c
Removing intermediate container e808b8afc9fa
Removing intermediate container 3afb95a832a9
Step 2/2 : EXPOSE 8500
 ---> Running in 336c84317529
 ---> 2dfb9e9d53ec
Removing intermediate container 336c84317529
Successfully built 2dfb9e9d53ec
Successfully tagged dummy:v0
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

It looks ok. Then step 6:

```
PS C:\GoWorkspace\src\hello> docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
dummy               v0                  2dfb9e9d53ec        20 seconds ago      706MB
golang              onbuild             5d82e356477f        8 months ago        699MB
```

Step 6 looks ok, then step 7:

```
PS C:\GoWorkspace\src\hello> docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
dummy               v0                  2dfb9e9d53ec        20 seconds ago      706MB
golang              onbuild             5d82e356477f        8 months ago        699MB
```

step 7 looks ok, then step 8:

```
PS C:\GoWorkspace\src\hello> kubectl run hello-universe --image=dummy:v0 --port=8500
deployment "hello-universe" created
```

Step 8, looks ok, then step 9:

```
PS C:\GoWorkspace\src\hello> kubectl get pods
NAME                              READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
hello-universe-779b57d89f-kxrwr   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          4s
```

Here, I doubt pod hello-universe is not Ready. In the above mentioned link, [the author has 1/1 mark, which means pod is ready. click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfqyi.png), while I got 0/1. Does it mean my pod is not ready yet?
Anyway, I continue with the step 10:

```
PS C:\GoWorkspace\src\hello> kubectl expose deployment hello-universe --type="LoadBalancer"
service "hello-universe" exposed
```

it looks ok, then continue with the step 11:

```
PS C:\GoWorkspace\src\hello> kubectl get services
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
hello-universe   LoadBalancer   10.108.204.167   <pending>     8500:31376/TCP   13s
kubernetes       ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          9m
```

Finally, I try get the service url (step 12), with following error message:

```
PS C:\GoWorkspace\src\hello> minikube service hello-universe --url
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
...
...
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
Error opening service: Could not find finalized endpoint being pointed to by hello-universe: Temporary Error: Endpoint for service is not ready yet
Temporary Error: Endpoint for service is not ready yet
Temporary Error: Endpoint for service is not ready yet
Temporary Error: Endpoint for service is not ready yet
```

With some search internet, I notice when I start minikube, I shall use proxy tag, I got other kind of error. I will create another question, but this time, the question would be short. Thank you to read my so looong question. The command with minikube start with proxy is  [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646527/install-minikube-in-windows-behind-proxy-fails) .

Comment: I am behind of GFW since I am located in mainland. gcr.io is blocked.